# MySQL show proportion

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to show a proportion of customers that signed up because he/she was being referred by other customers and customers with no referral. So far I only able to show it as numerical but **I wanted to show it in percentage**. *Null is when the customer signs up without being referred*.

The original data as follows:

```
CustomerID    ReferralID
1000004        1000003
1000015        1000010
1000007        1000004
1000011           Null
1000026        1000004
```

The query that I have and return data as follows:

```
select customerID, COUNT(*) as proportion
from company123.customertable
group by (customerID)
order by customerID asc;
```

```
CustomerID    proportion        
1000004         1               
1000015         1               
1000007         1              
1000011         1               
1000026         1
```

Expected result

```
CustomerID    referred        non-referred
1000004         1                  0
1000015         1                  0
1000007         1                  0
1000011         0                  1
1000026         1                  0
```

Any suggestion to show it as a percentage? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the actual output you are expecting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate function `AVG()`:

```
select avg(ReferralID is not null) referred,
       avg(ReferralID is null) non_referred 
from customertable
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8d302fc72f44862408e03718c702795b).
Results:

```
> referred | non_referred
> -------: | -----------:
>   0.8000 |       0.2000
```

Comment: thank you this also helps me to understand how to show proportion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use an aggregate function on a case statement like this

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) customers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN referral_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS referred,
    SUM(CASE WHEN referral_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS non_referred
FROM company123.customertable
```

should give you something like this (numbers are made up)

```
customers referred non_referred
12301     0.7128   0.2872
```

Comment: Hi, @Jpsh thank you for your solution, I have edited my query and it returns `customerID = 5, referred = 1, non referred = 0`. If I am looking at the original data, should it `referred = 4 and non-referred = 1`?

Comment: this has given me an idea to do the query. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way which will give a percentage to 2 decimal places:

EDIT: Added % sign to output using CONCAT

```
SELECT customerid,
       CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(ReferralID) * 100.0 / Count(*) as decimal(9,2)),'%') AS proportion 
FROM   company123.customertable
GROUP  BY customerid
ORDER  BY customerid ASC;
```